# prettyPhoto gallery not working in IE (any)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, photo-gallery, prettyphoto

Having had no luck getting a response on the prettyPhoto forums I decided to try my luck here. The original post:

I recently uploaded my very first website, a portfolio site for my gf. I used prettyPhoto for the galleries of her work, but came to the realization that the gallery does not work in IE (any version I have tried). You cant even click the thumbnail links to see the full-sized images.

Having read the FAQ I am certain it's not a "trailing comma" issue, as I've tested with a clean unaltered version of the prettyPhoto.js, and removing the css styles also did nothing to get the gallery to work in IE.
I am very new to webdesign, so my apologies if I am missing something obvious but I have not been able to figure out the problem thus far.

Link to random gallery on the site: http://www.sofievanassche.be/portfolio/school/bullying_book.html

Thank you for taking the time to read this post!

Comment: Not working in ff, too - wrong paths: http://www.sofievanassche.be/images/all/school/07_bullying_book/bullying_book_03.jpg And, yes, linux is case sensitive - replace .jpg with .JPG: http://www.sofievanassche.be/images/all/school/07_bullying_book/bullying_book_03.JPG

Comment: thanks, I noticed as much too and thought to have fixed it but I guess it didnt take, thanks again for letting me know :)

Comment: Updated the images to lowercase extensions but still not been able to get it to work in IE, any help very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i have found problem, do this:

```
 <a href="../../images/all/school/02_newspaper/newspaper_01.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]">
          <img src="../../images/all/gallery_thumbnails/school/02_newspaper/newspaper-thumb_01.jpg" alt="">
          </a>
```

**Wrap your images inside link (a tag), like above.** Your current code:

```
 <a href="../../images/all/school/02_newspaper/newspaper_03.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]"></a>
                  <img src="../../images/all/gallery_thumbnails/school/02_newspaper/newspaper-thumb_03.jpg" alt="">
```

question is actually - how this is working in other browsers. :)

Comment: well, the reason I did that initially was to be able to overlay a magnifying glass sprite on hover over the thumbnails (the anchor tag had a width and height same as the thumbnails and magnifying glass image as background on hover). but decided not to use that hover state in the end, and you are right! putting the images back into the anchor tags fixed the problem! :) thanks you very much for your time and effort

Comment: No problem, i had feeling that something small is in question. :)